# Why is display:block necessary when there is a image background?

Tags: css, background, block, overlap

The logo display well with the code below,

but I don't know How the code `display:block` works here?

I know if I don't use the code the text will overlap the image(the logo), but I don't understand, why is display:block can solve this?

The HTML:

```
<h1><a href="#">WebsiteName</a></h1>
```

The CSS:

```
#header h1 a {
background: url(images/logo.jpg) no-repeat;
height: 21px;
width: 197px;
display: block;/* How this works? */
text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the `<a>` element is an inline element. Inline elements can't have a set width or height.

By adding `display: block;`, you make the element block-level, which lets you set its size.

Answer (score 1):

Because a is not a block level element and you cannot set a width on it.  Block vs inline is really important to understanding CSS so you should really take some time and familiarize yourself with the concept.

It's a very important building *block* (teehee sorry for the pun)

http://webdesign.about.com/od/htmltags/qt/block_vs_inline_elements.htm